# A . 2kg tennis ball is thrown so it bounces straight up 5 meters high and comes back down. What are the potential and kinetic energy:

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, momentum, projectile

A . 2kg tennis ball is thrown so it bounces straight up 5 meters high and comes back down. What are the potential and kinetic energy:

A.)  when 5m high

B.) when reaches ground AGAIN

C.)  when it first left ground after bounce

D.)  what are the velocity and momentum at each of the above?)  when 5m high

Comment: These are simple kinematics and energy conservation questions. This site is to help learners who are stuck, so please show us some work you have already done.

Comment: I got two kilograms times meters over seconds for momentum for A and C.  Velocity I got 10 m/s for  and C.  For B would it be half the velocity?  And for B the momentum would be mass times a half of the velocity? This is why I'm confused.  Also since it's elastic collision KE is conserved so will it be 0 for all three cases?  Then what would the potential energy be once it bounces again on the ground (B)  half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the ball is thrown vertically down from an unspecified height and then bounces up off the ground to a height of 5m and then drops back down. I'll take g = 10 ms-2 as the numbers given in the question are clearly set for this value, and neglect air resistance and frictional losses in the ball.

Firstly, the sum of the kinetic and gravitational potential energy must remain constant.

A) So, At the top of its trajectory, 5m up, it has zero kinetic energy, and all its energy is GPE = 0.2 x 10 x 5 = 10 J

B) When it reaches the ground it has zero GPE and it's kinetic energy must be equal to 10 J = 1/2mv^2  so v = sqrt((2*10)/0.2) = sqrt(100) = 10 ms-1

C) When it first left the ground, after the first bounce, it must have the same velocity, 10 ms-1

D) Momentum at the top of the trajectory is zero, just before hitting the ground and just after the ball's momentum, mv, is 0.2 x 10 = 5 kgms-1

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to homework-like questions.  Our policy on this can be found [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/5739) which includes:  “If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.”  Please consider deleting this answer yourself.

Comment: So would potential energy be zero for c and kinetic 9.8j ?